# Deployment of Machine Learning models - Data versioning

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, azure-devops

Assume we have a Publish pipeline on the master branch of a repository hosted on Microsoft Azure. When a Pull Request is completed on this branch, an artefact is automatically built. When clicking on the artefact, we can see a window "Provenance" that shows the exact commit of the code used to publish the artefact (see image below).
[image]

Now assume an artefact is built using not only code, but also some heavy data. This is the case of Machine Learning models which are created with training code and training data. I want to be able to link the version of both to an artefact (the Machine Learning model) that, ideally, is created automatically after a PR on master.

Currently, I upload the artefact manually, so not only I lack the identifier of the data used to produce the ML model, but also the commit id of the code.

Is there a way on Azure to automatically produce the (heavy) artefact ? Is there a way to keep track of the id of the code *and* the data used to produce an artefact ?
I suppose I will need a data versioning system + a storage. Are these provided by Azure ?

Comment: What does your heavy data mean? Some files? If yes, you can try to create a Universal Packages to manage those data mean.

Comment: yes files in a structured format such as xml or json for instance

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way on Azure to automatically produce the (heavy) artefact ? Is there a way to keep track of the id of the code and the data used to produce an artefact ? I suppose I will need a data versioning system + a storage. Are these provided by Azure ?

If I understand you correct, you could try to use the Universal Package to pack those json files as artifact.

As test, we could use the Universal packages task to create and publish the artifact:

[image]

After the build complete, we could get the artifact in our feed:

[image]

You could check this document [Publish and download Universal Packages in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Universal packages with Azure DevOps Artifacts](https://geeks.ms/lfraile/2019/02/23/universal-packages-with-azure-devops-artifacts/) for some details.

Comment: actually, the goal is to produce an artefact that is the result of some data (the json files) and some code. I don't have constraints about how the data is stored for now, so I am cool about storing it as an artefact as you suggested; I would like to be able in a script to specify the resource where the data is stored, run some commands that create the ML model, and publish automatically the ML model as an artefact

Comment: i don't think so ,  I would like to be able in a script to specify the resource where the data is stored, run some code that create the ML model, and publish automatically the ML model as an artefact